# Problems with Dropbox since Ubuntu upgrade 14.10 -> 15.04

Tags: nautilus, 15.04, dropbox

I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04.

I have the problem that Nautilus crashes when I open the `Dropbox` folder from the icon in the top bar. The icons on the desktop disappear and the launcher just opens when I press the super button. Further everything is lacking afterwards, just a reboot helps. I reinstalled Dropbox already and tried the command `sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox`.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by saying `everything is lacking`, more details please. Also, could you open terminal, run command `tail -f /var/log/syslog > ~/dropbox_bug_log` and then reproduce dropbox/nautilus crash and reboot if needed. Then paste contents of the  `~/dropbox_bug_log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and share it with us.

Comment: Lacking means in this case after the icons disappeared I can maybe close a window or two and then windows (close, minimize buttons) and start bar as well as the power button in the upper right don't react to mouse clicking anymore. The only whay to shut down without force shutdown is pressing the power button at the notebook several times (or long for force shutdown). And only way to open the start bar is pressing the super key. but still mouse clicking on window bars and on the top bar have no effect.

Comment: The command don't works, terminal output after typing ~/dropbox_bug_log  --> bash: /home/~/dropbox_bug_log: Keine Berechtigung (it is: no authorization)

Comment: Opening the Dropbox folder from the shell is no problem, by the way.

Comment: And sometimes a Information Window after reboot appears telling: "Nautilus Restart Required

Dropbox requires Nautilus to be restarted to function properly." But after clicking the  "Restart Nautilus" button -> no icons on desktop and same problems as described above.

Comment: Confirmed, experiencing the same bug, also after the upgrade. I filed a bug ticket here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1465189 I'll update this answer once the ticked has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to [a bug in nautilus](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750528), which has been [fixed](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/commit/bfe878e4313e21b4c539d95a88d243065d30fc2c) in nautilus 3.14.3. The problem should disappear once the update rolls out.

As a workaround until then, you can either install 2.14.3 manually, or simply avoid using the button (instead opening the Dropbox folder from a nautilus window). If you happen to do it anyway by force of habit, you can restore the desktop by entering `nautilus -q ; nautilus & disown` on the command line (note that this will close any open nautilus windows).